# Phonegap, stop audio

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I tried to make an simple phonegap aplication, where several songs can be played.
So far my app can play an song, but when i tap twice the play button:

```
 <button onclick="playAudio('test.mp3')">Play Some Audio</button>
```

It plays the song again, so that an echo can be heard, instead of first stop the audio and  then beging from the beginning of the song.
I tried severeal things but either my stop button works. The Api for stop audio can be found here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#media.stop
This is my stop button:

```
 <button onclick="stopAudio()">Stop Some Audio</button>
```

and the entire project:

```
     <body>
     <h1>Playing Audio</h1>
      <button onclick="playAudio('test.mp3')">Play Some Audio</button>
      <button onclick="stopAudio()">Stop Some Audio</button>
      </div>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
        function playAudio(src) {
        if (device.platform == 'Android') {
            src = '/android_asset/' + src;
        }

        var media = new Media(src, success, error_error);

        media.play();

    }

    function success() {
        // ignore
    }

    function error_error(e) {
        alert('great error');
        alert(e.message);
    }

    function stopAudio() {
     if (media) {
     var media = new Media(src, success, error_error);
         media.stop();
         }
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

So maybe anybody know how to make that stop button work?
Sorry for my bad englisch and greetings from germany!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a flag when the audio has been played **audioPlaying** and check that flag each time to attempt to play the audio again. This is the most straight forward solution here.

Also you are using two different instances of your Media object, when you call stop on it you are referencing an entirely different instance. You need to increase the scope of your media object, see below:

EDIT: Added audioPlaying = false; to the stop function to prevent it getting stuck.

```
 <body>
 <h1>Playing Audio</h1>
  <button onclick="playAudio('test.mp3')">Play Some Audio</button>
  <button onclick="stopAudio()">Stop Some Audio</button>
  </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var audioPlaying = false;
    var media;
    app.initialize();
    function playAudio(src) {
        if (audioPlaying === false) {
            if (device.platform == 'Android') {
                src = '/android_asset/' + src;
            }

            media = new Media(src, success, error_error);

            media.play();
            audioPlaying = true;
        } else {
            //audio is already playing
        }
    }

function success() {
    // ignore
}

function error_error(e) {
    alert('great error');
    alert(e.message);
}

function stopAudio() {
 if (media) {
     media.stop();
     audioPlaying = false;
     }
}
</script>
```

Comment: your answer is absolutley correct! But did you find any possible reason that the stop audio isnt working? Here is an example that works:  http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#media.stop

Comment: With the code provided stop should now work, you were running the code: media = new Media() twice. As a result what you actually end up doing is calling play on one object and stop on another unrelated object. By creating one instance in scope of both functions the stop should work. Happy to help you debug further

Comment: unfortunately it does not work. What i also noticed is that after playing the sound, the audioPlaying stays false so that i can the song only one time.

Comment: add the audioPlaying = false which I have included in my answer on the stop function to fix that

Comment: I made a new question to that topic!! Please revise it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615376/javascript-variable-is-not-accesible-by-function/16615434?noredirect=1#16615434

Answer (score 1):

create a global variable `var media;` and assign it value when you click play button . instead of initializing it again and again

change your code like this hope it will work.

```
<body>
     <h1>Playing Audio</h1>
      <button onclick="playAudio('test.mp3')">Play Some Audio</button>
      <button onclick="stopAudio()">Stop Some Audio</button>
      </div>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        var media;
        app.initialize();
        function playAudio(src) {
        if (device.platform == 'Android') {
            src = '/android_asset/' + src;
        }

        media = new Media(src, success, error_error);

        media.play();

    }

    function success() {
        // ignore
    }

    function error_error(e) {
        alert('great error');
        alert(e.message);
    }

    function stopAudio() {
     if (media) {
         media = new Media(src, success, error_error);
         media.stop();
         }
    }
    </script>
</body>
```